# When mom is going to work, the kid says "Mom, come home to / with me soon, ok". Is that a correct expression?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

When mom is going to work, the kid says:

-"**Mom, come home to / with me soon, ok**". I am not sure "**to or with**"

or

-"**Mom, come home soon and be with me, ok**"

But I remember I read this sentence similar to this "**My wife is sick. I have to go home to her.**" somewhere

Comment: If you go home _with_ someone, you are both returning home together (or you are going with them to their home as a visitor).

Answer (score -1):

**With** implies two somethings that act together, like

> "with this sword I will defeat my foes"

which implies both the sword and the wielder will act.

however "to" in this context implies an addition to the current subject, such as ;

> "Go to work with your father, he needs your help!"

as for your question, the grammatical expression would be

> "Mom, come home to me soon, ok?"

the additonal "ok" changes it from a statement into a question in most scenarios, but is not a general rule. If you get confused try saying it out loud in both an interrogative tone and a neutral tone.